# change text size and position of annotate in a video

Tags: raspicam

I have a script to record a video and it annotates the datetime on the image every second. However, the annotation is a bit too large for the resolution so I want to change it and make it smaller. I have theses lines :

```
cam.annotate_background = Color('black')
cam.annotate_text = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Is there a way to reduce the annotated text size and to move it somewhere else than in the middle top ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the python package 'picamera':

You can use the attribute `annotate_text_size`.
Default value is 32. Valid values 6 to 160
[Picamera documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.annotate_text_size)

AFAIK it's not possible to change the location.